# How do i get kafka producer/consumer metrics using sarama

Tags: go, apache-kafka, metrics, sarama

I'm trying to get kafka producer/consumer metrics using sarama. But I'm unable to find any example on how to do the same. Can someone provide a sample implementation example?

I'm using the following code to get metrics of a broker. But what should be the config to get metrics of a producer/consumer. I'm assuming that it will not be the same. Correct me if I'm wrong

```
    saramaConfig := sarama.NewConfig()
    saramaConfig.Version = <BrokerVersion>
    client, err := sarama.NewClient(<brokerAddresses>, saramaConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Unable to create sarama client")
        panic(err)
    }
    config := client.Config()

    MeanIncomingByteRate := metrics.GetOrRegisterMeter(getMetricNameForTopic("incoming-byte-rate", topic), config.MetricRegistry).RateMean(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with. But I will try to answer.

You should register the `go-metrics` registry to the config.

This is an example of how to create a registry and use it (https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/Shopify/sarama.v2#example-Config-Metrics):

```golang
// Our application registry
appMetricRegistry := metrics.NewRegistry()
appGauge := metrics.GetOrRegisterGauge("m1", appMetricRegistry)
appGauge.Update(1)

config := NewConfig()
// Use a prefix registry instead of the default local one
config.MetricRegistry = metrics.NewPrefixedChildRegistry(appMetricRegistry, "sarama.")

// Simulate a metric created by sarama without starting a broker
saramaGauge := metrics.GetOrRegisterGauge("m2", config.MetricRegistry)
saramaGauge.Update(2)

metrics.WriteOnce(appMetricRegistry, os.Stdout)
```

So you should create the registry and set it to the config

```golang
appMetricRegistry := metrics.NewRegistry()
appGauge := metrics.GetOrRegisterGauge("m1", appMetricRegistry)
appGauge.Update(1)

    saramaConfig := sarama.NewConfig()
    saramaConfig.Version = <BrokerVersion>

    // set it here
    saramaConfig.MetricRegistry = metrics.NewPrefixedChildRegistry(appMetricRegistry, "sarama.")


    client, err := sarama.NewClient(<brokerAddresses>, saramaConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Unable to create sarama client")
        panic(err)
    }
    config := client.Config()

    MeanIncomingByteRate := metrics.GetOrRegisterMeter(getMetricNameForTopic("incoming-byte-rate", topic), config.MetricRegistry).RateMean(),
```

Comment: Getting all the metrics values as zero